# How to set the localization for a Gutenberg block?

Tags: block-editor, localization

I'm trying to set localization for a Gutenberg block. After scaffolding a basic block with wp-cli command `npx @wordpress/create-block`, I need to set localization. I've create my pot file and localization using wp-cli generating all json files needed.

Now how can I set up this in my plugin?

I'm registering block using metadata from block.json, where I have set up correctly textdomain.

I'm using this code to register block and load textdomain on PHP.

```
function create_block_gutenpride_block_init() {
   load_plugin_textdomain( 'gutenpride', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );

   register_block_type( __DIR__ );

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_block_gutenpride_block_init' );
```

Comment: "I'm trying to set localization for a Gutenberg block" - you meant, your code (e.g. the `edit` function) is using the `wp.i18n` functions like `__()`? Can you show more of your code, e.g. the edit function and the PHP code which enqueues the editor/block scripts?

Comment: The code I use to register the block is posted. This is a new syntax that load block.json metadata to register all block attributes and more. In my JS I use wp.i18n functions correctly, but for some reason translations are not loaded. Here's reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I just got confused with the [`render_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#php-server-side).. :p Anyway, I hope my answer helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Summary:** Perhaps like me, you just need to rename, relocate and/or manually load your script/JSON translations files?*

---

So I created a block using the [`npx @wordpress/create-block gutenpride`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) command, then I created the translation stuff (POT, PO, MO and JSON/JED files) and my plugin structure was like so (but some files like `src/*` were not included):

```
gutenpride/
    build/
        index.asset.php
        index.css
        index.js
        style-index.css
    languages/
        gutenpride-de_DE-1b3034803df8a21550db0d04471ea571.json
        gutenpride-de_DE.mo
        gutenpride-de_DE.po
        gutenpride.pot
    block.json
    gutenpride.php
```

- `1b3034803df8a21550db0d04471ea571` is the MD5 hash of relative path to the **built** editor script at `build/index.js`, i.e. in PHP, `md5( 'build/index.js' )`.
- In my block [metadata file (`block.json`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/), I got these lines:

  ```json
  "name": "create-block/gutenpride",
  ...
  "textdomain": "gutenpride",
  "editorScript": "file:./build/index.js",
  ```

And after debugging, I found out that if `textdomain` is not empty (i.e. a text domain is specified), then WordPress will automatically run the final step here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/#how-to-use-i18n-in-javascript, and in my case, WordPress called `wp_set_script_translations( 'create-block-gutenpride-editor-script', 'gutenpride' )` — see [`register_block_script_handle()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_script_handle/), but the script handle is basically `<block name>-editor-script` ( without any slashes (`/`) ).

So it's cool that the script translations are loaded automatically, but my JSON file was placed in the `languages` in my plugin folder, therefore I had to re-load the translations manually like so, which I called **after** the `register_block_type( __DIR__ )`:

```php
// ** first param = script handle; second param = text domain
wp_set_script_translations( 'create-block-gutenpride-editor-script', 'gutenpride',
    plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages/' ); // ** use a full absolute path
```

Alternatively, move/copy your JSON/JED files to the `wp-content/languages/plugins` folder and then you would not need to manually load the script translations. =) (so for example, you'd have `wp-content/languages/plugins/gutenpride-de_DE-1b3034803df8a21550db0d04471ea571.json`)

Additionally, I also removed the `./` in the editor script path, i.e. I used `"editorScript": "file:build/index.js"` instead, because otherwise, then WordPress would load the wrong file because the MD5 hash will be `dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9` ( i.e. `md5( './build/index.js' )` ) and not `1b3034803df8a21550db0d04471ea571` (which is what [`wp i18n make-json`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-json/) and plugins such as [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) would use).

Or if you don't want to change the `editorScript` value, then you'd need to edit the MD5 hash in the JSON file's name..

Comment: Many thanks for this! It's working now. So basically I have two choice: remove `./` from `block.json` or put the translations in main plugins folder. I was struggling to this for some days. This should be reported on documentation. Thanks

Comment: Yes, your 3rd sentence is basically correct, but more precisely, whether or not you put the translations in the `languages/plugins` folder, if the MD5 hash in your JSON/JED file names is **not** using the `./`, then you would still need to remove it from the `editorScript`. :)