# Localising a Block

Tags: block-editor, localization

I'm trying to localise my Gutenberg plugin and block, the PHP side is translated but zero luck on the js side.

I tried the official guide, few other blog posts, the solutions posted in this post [enter link description here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407346/using-wp-set-script-translations-without-manually-registering-the-script) and this one [enter link description here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/394062/how-to-set-the-localization-for-a-gutenberg-block) but nothing. Not even with the simplest block.

Maybe I'm missing something...
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

WordPress version: 6.1.1 , PHP version: 8.0.28 , WP-CLI version: 2.7.1

EDITED as other answers recommendations: Still not working

My structure:

```
/my-block/
      /build/
          - index.js
          - index.js.map
          - index.asset.php
      /src/
          - index.js
      /languages/
          - my-block-es_ES.mo
          - my-block-es_ES.po
          - my-block-es_ES.pot
          - my-block-es_ES-1fdf421c05c1140f6d71444ea2b27638.json

       - block.json
       - my-block.php
       - package.json
       - ...
```

The main PHP my-block.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       My Block
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           1
 * Text Domain:       my-block
 */

function create_block_my_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ );

    // Load MO files for PHP.
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-block', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_my_block_block_init' );


function script_translations(){
    // Load JSON files for JS - this is necessary if using a custom languages path!!
    wp_set_script_translations( 'my-block-local-edit-script', 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'script_translations' );
```

The block.json

```
{
   "apiVersion": 2,
   "title": "Test Gutenberg Block Title",
   "name": "my-block/local",
   "category": "layout",
   "textdomain": "my-block",
   "icon": "universal-access-alt",
   "editorScript": "file:build/index.js"
}
```

And the src/index.js that compiles into build/index.js

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

// Register the block
registerBlockType('my-block/local', {
   title: __('My Block Local', 'my-block'),
   edit: function () {
      return <p> {__('Hello world', 'my-block')} (from the editor)</p>;
   },
   save: function () {
      return <p> {__('Hello world', 'my-block')} (from the frontend) </p>;
   },
});
```

Comment: note that save components do not run on the frontend, their output is stored as static HTML in the posts content and then displayed, save components only run inside the editor, and their output is never shown in the browser. Additionally, the answer you linked to clearly states that `init` is far too early to call `wp_set_script_translations`, way way too early. It ***must*** happen after the block is registered and enqueued. `register_block_type` does not register and enqueue your blocks scripts, rather it adds hooks to do that in the future when the appropriate time occurs

Comment: This means that for `wp_set_script_translations` and `register_block_type` to be called in the same function to work would require some form of Dr Who level time travel

Comment: Changed the PHP to call wp_set_script_translation on wp_enqueue_script. Still not working :(

Comment: are there any JS errors in the console, and can you confirm that the raw HTML of the block editor page has either a reference to your JSON or contains a string that can only be found inside your translation? How are you testing this? You said it isn't working, but didn't ellaborate on how you determined that, or explained how it is not working and the steps you took to test this.

Comment: hmmm a reading of WP code suggests it already calls `wp_set_script_translation` when it registers the scripts handle if the needed textdomains are present in `block.json`, so calling it yourself is pointless unless you want to reorganise folders. Does the problem go away if you move the files up and stop trying to use a subfolder?

Comment: Thanks Tom for keep helping! Answering your comments:
No js errors. I'm testing it using it on my local WP. If I don't register the block throw PHP it doesn't load. No .json loaded on the code. Uploaded to GitHub https://github.com/jrausell/wp-plugin-localization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in your code:

1. As stated in my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/407513/137402), the script handle format is `<block name with slashes replaced with hypens>-editor-script`, so because your block name is `my-block/local`, then the script handle is `my-block-local-editor-script` and **not** `my-block-local-edit-script`.
2. The correct *action* name is `wp_enqueue_scripts` (note the "s") and not `wp_enqueue_script`. However, `wp_enqueue_scripts` would not work because that's for the front-end (non-admin side). For admin use like the post editing screen at `wp-admin/post.php`, you can use either [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) or a hook specific to the block/Gutenberg editor like [`enqueue_block_editor_assets`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/).
3. Your [JSON translation file](https://github.com/jrausell/wp-plugin-localization/blob/main/languages/my-block-es_ES-1fdf421c05c1140f6d71444ea2b27638.json) should also be using `dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9` which is the value of `md5( 'build/index.js' )` (no `./`). So the file name should instead be `my-block-es_ES-dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9.json`

   That value/hash is also what you'd get when you run this [via WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-json/): `wp i18n make-json my-block-<locale>.po ./ --no-purge` after doing a `cd languages` in your plugin directory.

How to fix the issues 1 and 2:

1. Change the `wp_set_script_translations()` line ([it's line 20 in your code](https://github.com/jrausell/wp-plugin-localization/blob/2fac84a24c567088d2b348c0914fdc961a9e7d88/my-block.php#L20)) to:

   ```php
   wp_set_script_translations(
       'my-block-local-editor-script',           // script handle
       'my-block',                               // text domain
       plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' // path to your translation files
   );
   ```

   Or you can use [`generate_block_asset_handle()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/generate_block_asset_handle/) to generate the script handle:

   ```php
   $script_handle = generate_block_asset_handle( 'my-block/local', 'editorScript' );
   wp_set_script_translations( $script_handle, 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
   ```
2. Change the `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'script_translations' );` ([line 22 in your code](https://github.com/jrausell/wp-plugin-localization/blob/2fac84a24c567088d2b348c0914fdc961a9e7d88/my-block.php#L22)) to:

   ```php
   add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'script_translations' );

   // These also work:
   //add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'script_translations' );
   //add_action( 'init', 'script_translations' );
   ```

   **Note about using `init`:** Calling `register_block_type()` will automatically and immediately *register* the block editor script — see [`register_block_script_handle()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_script_handle/), so `init` can be used to set the script translations as long as it's called after calling `register_block_type()`.

Comment: Thanks Sally!! now is working perfectly!