# Translating Gutenberg Block - JSON Translation Files Not Loading

Tags: block-editor, translation

In following the steps outlined in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/394062/how-to-set-the-localization-for-a-gutenberg-block) I am unable to get it to work with the setup that I have. Essentially I have all my custom blocks within a structure like so:

[image]

They are loaded in `functions.php` like this:

```
function custom_theme_block_init()
{
    $blocks = array(
        'accordion',
        'brand-animation',
        'brand-family',
        'brand-listing',
        'button-hoc',
        'custom-icons',
        'editor-experience',
        'grid-layout',
        'stories',
        'testimonial-showcase',
        'variations',
    );

    foreach ($blocks as $dir) {
        register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/blocks/build/' . $dir);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_theme_block_init');
```

My issue is the JSON files that `make-json` generates do not load. I've tried all the solutions presented in the aforementioned question I linked to above.

The block.json for the custom block highlighted in my screenshot (stories) is as follows:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "mativ/stories",
    "version": "1.1.7",
    "title": "Stories",
    "category": "mativ",
    "description": "Filterable content view of the Stories post type",
    "supports": {
        "html": false,
        "align": true
    },
    "attributes": {
        "postType": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "post"
        },
        "postTaxonomies": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        },
        "numPosts": {
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 4
        },
        "enablePagination": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "mativ",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "render": "file:./render.php",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
}
```

An example of my usage is as follows:
`__("Remove filter", metadata.textdomain)`

Comment: aside from the PHP block in your question there's no other code, can you show where it's being used on the javascript side? As well as where you're expecting to see the translated strings? As well as the `theme.json` you're using for one of the blocks that has the issue

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell - I've updated my initial question with some additional information. Let me know if there is anything else you'd like me to provide.

Comment: this issue might have nothing to do with gutenberg and everything to do with the use of a dynamic variable being used for the textdomain, language tools can't parse those variables because they can't load a browser and start WordPress, execute the add new post page, go to that page, load the editor, insert your block, then read what the second value passed to `__` was. It has to be a static string, it cannot be a variable unless you plan to write out your localisation files by hand manually

Comment: e.g. I strongly suspect if you change `__("Remove filter", metadata.textdomain)` to `__("Remove filter", 'mativ')` then you'll end up with a localised JSON file that has a single entry for `Remove filter`

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't believe that'll fix the issue as ultimately when the files are compiled to the `build` folder they will get resolved correctly to the value of contained within `metadata.textdomain` (which so happens to be 'mativ').

Comment: I think you missed why, the tools that generate the files are static so they can’t read the dynamic variables, neither will linters or the other tooling from core. It might not be the primary issue you’re facing but I guarantee it is incorrect and will cause other problems if it isn’t causing this. Sure at runtime it will figure out it has the value “mativ” but I’m not talking about runtime

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the tip - much appreciated! :) I've converted them all over to use a static string (mativ) but looks like those pesky JSON files are still not loading and/or are not being used.

FWIW the `make-json` utility does create two JSON files which I'm wondering is part of the problem. It creates one with a `source` value of `"source": "build\/stories\/index.js",` and another with a value of `build\/stories\/view.js`.

Comment: how are you building your files? Should there not be a singular JS file for your blocks editor/admin UI? Are the JSON files next to the built files or somewhere else? And I'm assuming that `Remove filter` was inside the edit component not the save component? Are you using a single translations file/POT for multiple blocks?

Comment: I believe there are two because there is a JS file for the front-end view and another for the edit view - both contain those translated strings. I ultimately gave us and just did my translations manually. I'm pretty sure it didn't work because I'm not doing this the plugin way.

Comment: can you be specific about where the language files are? You haven't mentioned where they're located in relation to the `block.json` and built files, use examples rather than descriptions